# сортировка используя Sort

Tags: java, сортировка

мне в методе нужно реализовать сортировку List используя объект класса Sort,
но я сделал используя обычный метод sort, но это не подходит, объясните и покажите пожалуйста как тут правильно сделать сортировку используя объект класса Sort

```
 public Iterable<PObject> findAll(Sort sort) {
    if (Boolean.TRUE) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented yet");
    }
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List pObjectList = null;
    try {
        pObjectList = objectMapper.readValue(file, List.class);
        if (sort != null) {            
            Collections.sort(pObjectList);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pObjectList;
```

Comment: в этом классе есть функции сортировки? По данным этого класса идет сортировка? Больше конкретики

Comment: Вопрос не в тему: а в каком случае в Вашем коде не будет сгенерировано исключение `NotImplementedException`?

Comment: нужно использовать класс Sort для сортировки
по примерам от сюда http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.data.domain.Sort
но я не понимаю пока что как

Comment: на счет исключения пока что не знаю, не разбирался в этом, но оно нужно

Comment: sort у меня здесь как опция  с помощью которой я должен осуществить сортировку